# pyspark add packages dependencies to pytest

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I want to run tests using pytest and have a few dependencies like `spark-avro`.

I've downloaded the appropriate [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.13/3.3.0) and put it in a folder called `spark_jars/`.
This is for example my spark fixture, you can see I'm trying to use every single configuration to use this jar.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark():
    spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .config("spark.jars", "path/to/spark_jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar")
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "path/to/spark_jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar")
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "path/to/spark_jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    )
    yield spark
    spark.stop()
```

And if I try to use it in a test

```py
def test_something(spark):
    df = spark.read.format("avro").load("some/path/simple.avro")
```

I get the usual error that says I don't have the appropriate dependency

Things I have double checked, and am sure of -

- The version of spark matches the version of the jar (`spark 3.3.0`)
- All paths of files are correct, both jars and data file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try configuring the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` in your environment variables before starting the spark context?

```py
import os 
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = (
    "--jars path/to/spark_jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar"
    "--driver-class-path 'path/to/spark_jars/' "
    "pyspark-shell"
)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark():
    spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    )
    yield spark
    spark.stop()
```

You can set the environment variable at the top of your conftest.py. I did this to configure some Delta jars before and it worked. This will require the jars to be present before starting your application.

Also, you can use the `packages` argument in the same env var to download the JAR and use it in your application, without having to point to any specific path:

```py
import os 
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = (
    "--packages spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar"
    "pyspark-shell"
)
```